# How to convert javascript request to curl

Tags: javascript, curl

I have following code at javascript(node) and want to convert it to curl

```
const body = {
  'Email': "my email:)",
  'EncryptedPasswd': "my encrypted pass",
  'service': 'androidmarket',
  'accountType': 'HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE',
  'has_permission': '1',
  'source': 'android',
  'androidId': "my id",
  'app': 'com.android.vending',
  'device_country': 'us',
  'operatorCountry': 'us',
  'lang': 'en_US',
  'sdk_version': '23'
};

return _request.postAsync({url: _opts.loginUrl, gzip: true, json: false, form: body})
  .spread(function (res, body) {
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
      throw new LoginError(body);
    }
    assert(res.statusCode === 200, 'login failed');
    assert(res.headers['content-type'] === 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'utf8 string body');
    const response = responseToObj(body);
    if (!response || !response.auth) {
      throw new Error('expected auth in server response');
    }

    // set the auth token member to the response token.
    _opts.authToken = response.auth;
    return response.auth;
  });
```

And my curl request here:

```
curl --data "Email==myemail&EncryptedPasswd=mypass&has_permission=1&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&add_account=1&service=androidmarket&has_permission=1&source=android&device_country=us&lang=en_US&sdk_version=23&androidId=3c816e5b68106eb2&app=com.android.vending&operatorCountry=us" https://android.clients.google.com/auth
```

I tried many times run javascript script and always worked. And i can't see any difference between those script but js code works, curl doesn't

Comment: What does your curl request returns?

Comment: What do you mean with curl doesn't work? Do you get an error message? What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to your JavaScript, it is a `POST` request, which you haven't specified in your curl command.

```
curl \
-X POST \
--data "Email==myemail&EncryptedPasswd=mypass&has_permission=1&accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&add_account=1&service=androidmarket&has_permission=1&source=android&device_country=us&lang=en_US&sdk_version=23&androidId=3c816e5b68106eb2&app=com.android.vending&operatorCountry=us" \
https://android.clients.google.com/auth
```

Here is the syntax:

```
curl -X POST -d '&param1=1&param2=2...' URL
```

Comment: The `--data` implies a `POST` as the docs states: _"Sends the specified data in a POST request"_.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier to read, I would place each field on a separate line. You need a slash to separate each line.

In the question you have two equal signs for the email (`Email==myemail`). Could that be it? Also having these fields separate like this and putting them in the same order as the JavaScript fields could help you compare the two lists and make sure they are indeed equal.

```
curl --data "Email=myemail" \
     --data "EncryptedPasswd=mypass" \
     --data "has_permission=1" \
     --data "accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE" \
     --data "add_account=1" \
     --data "service=androidmarket" \
     --data "has_permission=1" \
     --data "source=android" \
     --data "device_country=us" \
     --data "lang=en_US" \
     --data "sdk_version=23" \
     --data "androidId=3c816e5b68106eb2" \
     --data "app=com.android.vending" \
     --data "operatorCountry=us" \
         https://android.clients.google.com/auth
```